# How can I store my own path in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

It's always a bit tedious to go from `$HOME` to some directory to run something, so is there a way I can save a directory to like `$MYPATH` and do `cd $MYPATH` from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html

so everytime you start a session you can

```
export MYPATH="path where you want to go to"
```

alternatively you can save the above line in the `~/.bashrc` this way when you start a new session, the variable is set automatically